# jquery addition in ajax result value not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to add the result value plus already exists value in that textbox. but addition is not working concatenation is working

```
$.post('includes/ajax_timesheet.php', {
  'action': 'add_kitamount',
  'jobnumber': jobno,
  'invoiceno': inv_no
}, function (data) {
  var tot1 = $('#tot_dayrate').val();
  var tot2 = $.trim(data);
  var tot = tot1 + tot2;
  alert(tot);
  $("#tot_dayrate").val(tot);
});
```

Comment: use like `var tot = parseFloat(tot1) + parseFloat(tot2); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation is happening because the values are being treated as string by + operator . Parse the values to number using any of the availaible javascript functions and then you will get correct total.

Ofcourse you need to handle for invalid inputs . Below is only showing an example for parse to number function.

```
var tot = parseInt(tot1) + parseInt(tot2);
```

Check [**here for string to number conversion**](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html) and good explanation of difference between `Number()` and `parseInt()` , `parseFloat()` functions.

Comment: additionally, you'll need to check result of `parseInt()` for the **NaN**'ness =). like `isNaN(parseInt(tot1)) ? 0 : parseInt(tot1)`

Answer (score 1):

**Convert to number**

```
var tot = Number(tot1) + Number(tot2);
```

**Or**

```
var tot = parseInt(tot1) + tot2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var tot = parseFloat(tot1) + parseFloat(tot2);
```

Answer (score 0):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns the value of the element in String. You will first need to convert to to Number for performing arithmetic operations.

You can use [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) to convert the string into numbered format.

So your code would look something like this,

```
var tot1 = $('#tot_dayrate').val();
if(tot1!='') {
    tot1=Number(tot1);
}
var tot2 = $.trim(data);
if(tot2!='') {
   tot2=Number(tot2);
}
var tot = tot1 + tot2;
```

Make sure to check for blank value before converting String into int.